# Java Resizable JLabel icon just keeps getting bigger

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, image-resizing

(EDIT 2) Hey guys i dont have a lot of time so i'll post this quick, i got the problem to happen in a smaller program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public class Main extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField txtWhatTheHell;

private static ArrayList<ImageIcon> thumbslist = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
public static DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();


private static void initialize_pix() throws IOException
{
    File filefolder = new File("pix");
    File[] pictures = filefolder.listFiles();


    for(File a: pictures)
    {
        Image tempimage = ImageIO.read(a);
        ImageIcon perimage = new ImageIcon(tempimage);

        thumbslist.add(perimage);
    }
    model.addElement(filefolder.toString());
}

public static ImageIcon resize(ImageIcon source, JLabel label)
{

    int height = label.getHeight();
    int width = label.getWidth();

    Image original = source.getImage();

    BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D graphics = resized.createGraphics();

    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    graphics.drawImage(original, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    graphics.dispose();

    ImageIcon result = new ImageIcon(resized);

    return result;
}







public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        initialize_pix();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main frame = new Main();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Main() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 731, 563);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

    txtWhatTheHell = new JTextField();
    txtWhatTheHell.setText("Text");
    txtWhatTheHell.setEditable(false);
    txtWhatTheHell.setColumns(10);

    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
    toolBar.setFloatable(false);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent a) {


            label.setIcon(resize(thumbslist.get(0), label));
        }
    });
    label.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    label.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
    gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(toolBar, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 685, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 491, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(label, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 188, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(txtWhatTheHell, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 188, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                .addContainerGap())
    );
    gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(toolBar, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 85, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(txtWhatTheHell, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 162, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(label, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 239, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 407, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
    );

    JList list = new JList(model);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent a) {

            if(list.isSelectionEmpty() == true)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                label.setIcon(thumbslist.get(0));
            }


        }
    });
    scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
    contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
}
}
```

The file at the beginning is a file of pictures
I'm really not sure what's wrong with it

(EDIT 3) I did a a delay after each instance the resize listener is invoked, and the very first time, it is resized correctly, then it seems after that it starts to grow out of control

i think that @HovercraftFullOfEels thought this, but i just do not know exactly what to do in order to make it resize only once every time the frame is resized

Answer (score 3):

You've got recursion of a sorts going on inside your component listener. Since you increase the size of the JLabel's icon within its own ComponentListener, the listener is notified of the change in size, which increase's the icon's size, which notifies the listener of the change in size....

A possible solution: consider turning off the listener within itself so that this recursion doesn't happen, and then turning it back on again. One way to do this is to simply remove and then re-add the listener within itself.

e.g.,

```
Label thumbchanger = new JLabel();
thumbchanger.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent a) {
        // remove the *this* component listener before resizing
        thumbchanger.removeComponentListener(this);
        Mod current_mod = Globals.modList.get(list.getSelectedIndex());
        ImageIcon new_icon = Globals.resize(current_mod.get_current(), thumbchanger);
        thumbchanger.setIcon(new_icon);
        // re-add the component listener after done resizing
        thumbchanger.addComponentListener(this);
    }
});
```

Another way is to use a boolean field local to the listener that you set within it.

```
thumbchanger.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    private boolean resizing = false;

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent a) {
        if (resizing) {
            return;
        }

        resizing = true;

        Mod current_mod = Globals.modList.get(list.getSelectedIndex());
        ImageIcon new_icon = Globals.resize(current_mod.get_current(), thumbchanger);
        thumbchanger.setIcon(new_icon);

        resizing = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem completely. Using either one of these methods doesn't even let the resizing listener to be activated at all. I just dont get what's wrong with it because i use the EXACT SAME method in another program and it works just fine!!

Comment: @MinhazMurks: then you need to 1) create and post as an edit to your question a valid [sscce](http://sscce.org) and 2) describe in detail your expected vs. observed behaviors.

Comment: Post a [mcve]/SSCCE. A bunch of uncompilable code snippets is neither.

Comment: @MinhazMurks: We can neither compile nor run the code you've posted, so how can we help? Please comment back when you've posted a true [sscce](http://sscce.org). Again we don't want the full code or code in a link but rather a new small program that illustrates your problem for us.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok i understand what you want me to do now, i will do that today :D

Comment: @MinhazMurks -- A prediction: once you isolate the error by creating your SSCCE, you will see for yourself what is causing it and be able to solve it yourself. If so, then please let us know.